# I want to change the Django list output format

Tags: django

I want to change the Django list output format.

I want to change the output format of list

The view code is as follows:

```
def team_todo_list(request, team_name):
    print("team_name : ", team_name)

    teamId = TeamInfo.objects.get(team_name = team_name).id
    team_leader_name = TeamInfo.objects.get(team_name = team_name).leader.username

    print("team_leader_name : ", team_leader_name)

    team_member = TeamMember.objects.filter(team=teamId)
    classification_list = Classification.objects.all()
    team_name= team_name

    member_array = []
    for member in team_member:
        # print(member.member.id) # nomad_coder, terecal
        member_array.append(member.member)

    team_todo_list = Todo.objects.filter(author__in=member_array)

    print('team_todo_list : ' , team_todo_list)
    print('team_member : ' , team_member)

    return render(request, 'todo/team_todo_list.html', {
        "team_todo_list":team_todo_list,
        "team_member_list":team_member,
        "classification_list":classification_list,
        "team_name":team_name,
        "team_leader_name": team_leader_name
    })
```

The template code is:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="todo_list">
        <tr>
            <td>check</td>
            <td>class</td>
            <td>manager</td>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>remaining time</td>
            <td>deadline</td>
        </tr>

        {% if team_todo_list.exists %}
        {% for p in team_todo_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{p.pk}}" class="td_check">
            </td>
            <td>{{p.classification}}</td>
            <td>{{p.author}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="" id={{p.id}} class="title_for_list">
                    {{p.title}} (<font color="blue"> from {{p.director}}</font> )
                </a><br>
                <a class="badge badge-pill badge-dark" href="{% url "todo:todo_edit" p.id %}">modify</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if p.dead_line %}
                {{p.remaining_time}}
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{p.dead_line}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <tbody id="tbody_todo"></tbody>
        {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <h4>there is no article</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}

    </table>
```

Currently in this format

[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJvvv.jpg)

I want to change it like this.

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCFVy.jpg)

Thanks for telling us how to modify the view or the template to change the output format of the list.

Thank you very much for telling us how

problem is resolved by this code

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="todo_list">


        {% regroup team_todo_list by author as author_list %}

        {% for author in author_list %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <h4>
                        {{ author.grouper }}
                    </h4>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>체크</td>
                <td>분류</td>
                <td>담당</td>
                <td>title</td>
                <td>남은 시간</td>
                <td>마감 기한</td>
            </tr>

            {% for todo in author.list %}

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{todo.pk}}" class="td_check">
                </td>
                <td>{{todo.classification}}</td>
                <td>{{todo.author}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" id={{p.id}} class="title_for_list">
                        {{todo.title}} (<font color="blue"> from {{todo.director}}</font> )
                    </a><br>
                    <a class="badge badge-pill badge-dark" href="{% url "todo:todo_edit" todo.id %}">수정</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if todo.dead_line %}
                        {{todo.remaining_time}}
                    {% else %}

                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>{{todo.dead_line}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag, which allow you to group your data when rendering in Django template. Like so:

```
{% regroup team_todo_list by author as author_list %}

{% for author in author_list %}
    <p>Author name: {{ author.grouper }}</p>
    {% for todo in author.list %}
        <p>Show your todo here {{ todo }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

- `author` is the keyword which you want to group on
- `author_list` is the list of grouped data
- `.grouper` is the value of the field which you're grouping on
- `.list` is the list of item which grouped by the field

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply

I solved the problem by telling you

I succeeded in converting it to the format I wanted.

Thanks for the great way

Comment: @ Toan Quoc 
It was easy to apply thanks to the detailed answers

Thank you for your kind reply

Answer (score 0):

My answer suggests that your `views.py` is okay.

```
  <table class="table table-no-border" id="todo_list">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>check</th>
            <th>class</th>
            <th>manager</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>remaining time</th>
            <th>deadline</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>


      {% for p in team_todo_list %}
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="user">
                {{p.author}}
            </td>
         </tr>

         {% if team_todo_list.exists %}
         <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{p.pk}}" class="td_check">
            </td>
            <td>{{p.classification}}</td>
            <td>{{p.author}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="" id={{p.id}} class="title_for_list">
                    {{p.title}} (<font color="blue"> from {{p.director}}</font> )
                </a><br>
                <a class="badge badge-pill badge-dark" href="{% url "todo:todo_edit" p.id %}">modify</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if p.dead_line %}
                {{p.remaining_time}}
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{p.dead_line}}</td>
         </tr>
         {% endfor %}

         {% comment %}
            I don't know what this tbody is for so I would comment it out
            <tbody id="tbody_todo"></tbody>
         {% comment %}

         {% else %}
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <h4>there is no article</h4>
            </td>
         </tr>
         {% endif %}

       </tbody>
     {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Then you can style your CSS table similar to this:

```
.table-no-border {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}

th, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.user{
    border:none;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

- Just the placement of the `for` loop, the `if-else` statement and slight `css` can change the looks.

Comment: Is this possible?

I'll try this method

Thank you for the smart way ~!